# find out what qmake executable is used inside a pro file

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

I need to call qmake in one of the make target commands. The question is how can I figure out which qmake has been called when executing this qmake. Like when in a bash script you ask for the executable.

Obviously I'm in an environment with multiple Qt installations, including defaults of Ubuntu 14.04 and qmake is the decider of which libraries are going to be fed into compilation (I'm not 100% sure on the later).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#accessing-qmake-properties

`$$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/qmake` should be the path.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a line that prints the version:

```
qmake --version
```

Comment: Your suggested solution gives me a random value. What if I've called the qmake with /home/peti/qt/bin/qmake, while qmake -> /usr/bin/qmake?